# JPA updatable attribute and JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I have made a couple of observations in my test and I am finding them hard to understand. My tests perform some basic update (or merge) operations on an Entity which has one of its attribute set as updatable=false.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "some-generator")
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME", updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "OBJECT_VERSION")
    private int version;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Note - I am using Hibernate as my persistence provider.

My observations and doubts are

1. The name property of the above Employee entity has updatable="false" set. If I load and set the name property of an employee entity and then call entityManager.merge(employee) the merge does not execute any update query which is the expected behavior but it does not throw any exception too. Is it possible to configure JPA such that an runtime exception is thrown?
2. Instead of calling entityManager.merge(employee), if the name property is updated using an JPQL query, the query executes successfully and the name property gets updated. What is the technical reasoning behind JPQL query behavior being different from JPA object update and why?
3. If the update is executed using a JPQL query the version number is not incremented despite the @Version annotation. I understand that this behavior can be achieved by adding the "versioned" keyword in the update query but I would like to understand the technical reasoning behind the version property not be updated when JPQL query is executed.

Since JPQL is an object oriented query language (like HQL is), I think there should not be   technical implementation issues for points 2 and 3. It would be great to hear some expert comments on this. Thanks.

Comment: I faced the same problem about merge. I did not find this question, so I have another open [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108064/unexpected-behaviour-of-entitymanager-merge). The main problem I found was merge returns an object, which never persisted, nor will ever persist. I'm filing a bug about this. -Atul

Answer (score 2):

1. Well the specs simply say that when a column is updateable="false" it should be ignored by the generated SQL. Doesn't say anything about throwing an exception. You can however implement that using listeners. Just declare a method in your bean like "checkModif", annotate it with `@PreUpdate` and throw an exception from it if the field is modified (note however that this will effectively cancel the operation, and nothing will be updated)
2. That's more likely a Hibernate bug. The JPA2 specs simply say that when a field is annotated with  `@Column(name = "EMP_NAME", updatable = false)` the corresponding column should be ignored by the SQL generated by the provider. Doesn't say anything about a particular case when that SQL comes from JPQL. There's many little "mishaps" like this in Hibernate's JPA2 implementation (like not being able to search using the key in a map association
3. AFAIK, the version number should be incremented only when using optimistic locking so when using JPQL you must specify if you actually want to increment it or not.

Example:

Scenario 1: You want to get an Employee entitity and then modify it. If you actually do some modifications to the Employee entity, you want those modifications persisted only if noone else also made some modifications to the same entity in the time between when you first read it and the time you commit your modification. For this to happen you read your entity like this:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EMPLOYEE e where e.id=3");
query.setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
Employee e = query.getSingleResult();
```

This way, if some other user uses the same above code to read the same entity while you're modifying it, and this new guys is quicker than you and commits a modification faster than you, then if you yourself modify something and try to commit you'll get an OptimisticLockException and you will not get your modifs commited, thus not overriding the (unknown by you at this point) modifs that the other guy did.

Scenario 2. You want to be sure to read an entity and when you save it, even though you didn't modify anything in it you want to only persist it (with the same values) if noone else modified anything else inthe mean time as well. For this you do

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EMPLOYEE e where e.id=3");
query.setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
//etc etc...
```

In both scenarios the Employee entity must have a versioned field for this to work:

```
@Version
protected int version;

public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

Comment: Can you detail on point 3? When I add @Version annotation I am actually telling hibernate to use optimistic locking right? So I didn't understand the need of specifying "versioned" keyword in the hql/jpql query.

Comment: Nope, when you add versioned you're NOT telling Hibernate's JPA implementation to use optimistic lock. To do that you either use the EntityManager or Query objects (which have methods such as setLockType etc). Read this: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjhz.html and the following chapter for details on how locks are used and work.

Comment: Ok. As the above link says "By adding a version attribute, the entity is enabled for optimistic concurrency control.". So are you indicating that JPQL implementation of the persistence provider (hibernate) would not look at the entity attributes? I say this because the above employee entity already has the @version property and hence I expected the JPQL query to increment the version since I am using optimistic locking.

Comment: Check out my initial answer. I've updated it with code examples.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed examples. Basically we are saying that when using JPQL or HQL, we need to explicitly set the lock mode (in addition to defining a version property in the model) to tell the underlying persistence provide that optimistic locking should be used. This is not needed when we deal with entityManager (in case of JPA) or hibernate session.